# Mage::getStoreConfig not working

Tags: magento-enterprise

I have set the multiple select option in system configuration. 
I need to get the selected values. 
I used the following,
Mage::getStoreConfig('customer/group_location/data')

But I didn't get anything. Somebody help me

below is the system.xml code

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <sections>
        <customer translate="label" module="customer">
            <groups>
                <group_location translate="label">
                    <label>Group Location</label>
                    <sort_order>200</sort_order>
                    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    <fields> <!-- Add Group location under customer configuration -->
                        <data>
                            <label>Group Location</label>
                            <frontend_type>multiselect</frontend_type>
                            <source_model>customerattribute/attribute</source_model>
                            <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                            <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                            <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                            <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                            <can_be_empty>1</can_be_empty>
                        </data>
                    </fields>
                </group_location>
            </groups>
        </customer>
    </sections>
</config>
```

Comment: Can you post the code from system.xml and config.xml

Comment: added system.xml @philwinkle

Comment: What if you change to a simple text field without source model? Do you manage to get something ?

Answer (score 2):

Just an idea...

Change `data` for any other identifier, as personal as you can, as it's a very common alias in Magento for getting data

Comment: That's a good idea I thought about it too, I was waiting for the OP to answer my comment before suggesting this.